# The same space between line

Tags: html, css

I have following info block:

```
        <div class="info-block">
            <p style="font-size: 18px; margin-top: 18px; margin-left: 10px; white-space: nowrap; width: 95%; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; "><?=$last['title']?></p>
            <p style="font-size: 18px; margin-top: 8px; margin-left: 10px;"><span class="price"><?=$last['price']?></span> тг.</p>
            <p style="font-size: 15px; margin-top: 18px; margin-left: 10px;"><?php
                if ($last['book_type'] ==   "book") echo "<img src='/images/green-time.png' style='width: 20px;vertical-align: top;'><span> ".$last['book_title']."</span>";
                else echo "<img src='/images/red-time.png' style='width: 20px;vertical-align: top;'><span> ".$last['book_title']."</span>";
            ?></p>
```

So there are three lines, I want to make space  between third and second line the same as between first and second line:

[image]

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your second block has `margin-top: 8px;` (defining space between first and second blocks) while the third has `margin-top: 18px;`, defining space between second and third blocks.

To make them equal, substitute `8px` with `18px` in this line:

```html
            <p style="font-size: 15px; margin-top: 18px; margin-left: 10px;"><?php
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry, my mistake it's resolved fixing the margin-top